# write a one year calendar to file using python

Tags: python-2.7, calendar

When I run the below code it prints out a calendar for an entire year (which I don't want). I want it to write to file but it won't. It also returns the error message `TypeError: expected a character buffer object`. Also, casting it into a string doesn't work.

```
import calendar

cal = calendar.prcal(2015)

with open('yr2015.txt', 'w') as wf:
    wf.write(cal)
```

As an example, the below code prints one month of a year and returns a string, but this isn't what I want

```
print calendar.month(2015, 4)
print type(calendar.month(2015, 4))
```

So when I run the below code I get the error message `<type 'NoneType'>`. It seems to me that it should be a string but obviously isn't. Any suggestions on how I can get a 12-month calendar into a text file?

```
print type(calendar.prcal(2015))
```

Comment: `<type 'NoneType'>` is not an error message. It's telling you the type of your object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`prcal` doesn't return anything. Use `cal = calendar.TextCalendar().formatyear(2015)` Instead.

Comment: This is a solution that better meets my needs.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a bit confusing. However, you don't have to make python write to the file.
Let python write to stdout and redirect stdout to a file

```
python myCal.py > yr2015.txt
```

This should do the trick

Answer (score 1):

That is because `calendar.prcal()` will only print the calendar of an year. And it wont return you any values. So this line in your code `print type(calendar.prcal(2015))` will return none type error.